# Getting a scoped component from a IDocumentStoreListener

Tags: dependency-injection, ravendb, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET 5 app using RavenDB, and I'm trying to create an attribute that will create a "Changeset" document with the keys of all the documents that were stored by the action.

For that purpose, I created an `ActionFilterAttribute` instantiated via `ServiceFilterAttribute`, which is registered as **Scoped**, that sets a flag on another **Scoped** component, let's call it `ChangesetAccessor`, which holds the list of changes.

The `IDocumentStore` is obviously a **Singleton**, and the listener (`IDocumentStoreListener` implementation) is manually instantiated. It needs access to the current `ChangesetAccessor`, so I thought giving it a reference to the `IServiceProvider` so it can call `GetService<ChangesetAccessor>` as needed would be enough, but it is receiving a different instance.

How can I get the `ChangesetAccessor` for the "current request" from my listener?

Comment: Which service provider are you giving it access to? It should be `IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices`, iirc, to get the request-specific service provider.

Comment: @MattDeKrey I am using (probably incorrectly) the one used to instantiate the Singleton `IDocumentStore`. How could I provide it with an `IHttpContextAccessor` (which is scoped itself, IIRC)?

Comment: `IHttpContextAccessor` isn't actually scoped - just the value it provides is. It's magic!(https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/62e534977386ebb02bfc351ec4a6bbea9ea7f635/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/HttpContextAccessor.cs)

Comment: @MattDeKrey you are right - it uses `CallContext`. Can you turn this into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually access `RequestServices` off of the `HttpContext` to get scoped instances. It's kind of backwards, and really will depend on `Microsoft.AspNet` to do it, but it will work for your situation; interestingly, [`IHttpContextAccessor`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/62e534977386ebb02bfc351ec4a6bbea9ea7f635/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/HttpContextAccessor.cs#L34-45) is a singleton, too, though it gives you a scoped value.

```
// injected:
IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

// in your method:
httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ChangesetAccessor>()
```